# Why can't the Sprint HTC One use GSM ROMs?

Tags: sim-unlocking, htc-one, carriers, att, sprint

Everywhere I've looked, I've found that the HTC One physical hardware (USA) is the same regardless of the carrier--all models of the USA phone containing both CDMA and GSM radios.

If this is the case, why can't the Sprint variant of the HTC One be hacked to work *properly* (see issues with Sprint-variant SIM unlocking [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2586704)) with USA GSM networks like AT&T? Or use GSM  ROMs for that matter if all the USA hardware has both radios.

I ask because I made the mistake of buying a Sprint HTC One on eBay with the intent of unlocking to use with my existing AT&T account. NOTE: I am not talking about 4G/LTE data, only 2G and 3G.